# Insert the line with special character (forward slash) in a file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Script to insert line in file

```
> cat text
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/neeraj/yocto/poky/meta \
  /home/neeraj/yocto/poky/meta-yocto \
  /home/neeraj/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  "
```

In that I have to insert a line below a pattern as

```
> cat text
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/neeraj/yocto/poky/meta \
  /home/neeraj/yocto/poky/meta-yocto \
  /home/neeraj/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/neeraj/yocto/poky/meta-ti \
  "
```

Comment: Can you show what work you have done so far?

Comment: @asimovwasright: I am trying to use `sed -i '/OLD/a \ NEW' file` type commands in which I am  appending NEW line below OLD line.

Answer (score 0):

(Not tested)
Probably what you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v search="$1" -v add="$2" '$0 ~ search{$0=$0"\n"add}1' "$3" >$4

exit
```

Where you would execute with the following format:

```
user@system:$ ./path-to-script.sh "Line you want to find" "Line you want to add" Input_File Output_File
```

Let me know if this needs more explanation. :-)

Comment: Please note the quotations on the arguments are **not** optional except for the in and out files

Comment: You could also drop the `"$3" >$4` in the script, and change the command to be more linux appropriate: 
`user@system:$ ./path-to-script.sh "Line you want to find" "Line you want to add" <Input_File >Output_File` 
Using proper input/output controls.

Comment: @suneet-saini ?? It's customary to keep track of your own questions, and either accept the answer or comment. Otherwise when people have the same question in the future, there will be no verification that this is the right answer. This forum is for everyone's benefit, not just the person asking the question.